# My plot graph is not showing in my pyqt5.QtWidgets

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I'm currently learning how can I use `pyqt5` with `matplotlib` together so  implement this code which will popup after I press a pushbutton in another window

I create another class called `canvas` in order to create multiple graphs in the future like bar chart and histogram

when I run this code the windows will appear and the pushButton also will appear but not the canvas that I did create

how can I show the canvas ( pie chart ) in the main window

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def setupUi(self,Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(900, 500)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 380, 141, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        

        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=8, height=4)
        self.canvas.move(0,0)

 
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
        
        

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "output window"))


class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, width = 5, height = 5, dpi = 100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
      
        self.plot()

    def plot(self):

        x = np.array([50, 30,40])
        labels = ["Apples", "Bananas", "Melons"]
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.pie(x, labels=labels)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = window()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Use `self.axes` instead of `ax`. You are creating a new Axes object when you call the `plot` method of your Canvas and it dies immediately. You might also have to throw a `self.draw()` in there after plotting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused because you are modifying the code generated by Qt Designer without understanding the consequences of it. The class generated by QtDesigner is not the window but a class that just populates the window. For example in your case with the window modification it is QMainWindow that has the canvas but you have created another widget called Dialog which is the one you show (if you check the QPushButton it is a child of Dialog so it is also shown). On the other hand, you only have to create a single axes.

Therefore, you should not modify the class generated by QtDesigner but rather create another class that inherits from a widget, and use the previous class to fill it.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys


class Ui_Dialog:
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(900, 500)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 380, 141, 61))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "output window"))


class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=5, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.plot()

    def plot(self):
        x = np.array([50, 30, 40])
        labels = ["Apples", "Bananas", "Melons"]
        self.axes.pie(x, labels=labels)
        self.draw()


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=8, height=4)
        self.canvas.move(0, 0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: okay i will code the UI by my self to understand more but i have one question more if you don't mind i try to call it after importing it from another page by using this function on a pushbutton but its not callable because the dialog contain Qdialog wich is not callable`def view_graph_output(self):
        self.window1=QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui=Dialog()
        self.window1.show()
`

Comment: @RabeeQasem I only answer what the OP asks in his post, other problems you have I will not answer since with the little information you provide it is impossible. Please read [ask] and if you have a new problem then create a new post.

Comment: okay thanks, I will try to solve it by my self :D